# jQuery update Google Map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to update a google map v3 with jQuery and at the moment it loads the map but when `.preview` is clicked the map scaled to the width and height and then goes grey.

```
$('.preview').click(function(){
    var width = $('#width').val();
    var height = $('#height').val();
    $('#map').css({
        'width':width,
        'height':height
    });
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
    var updateOptions = {
        zoom: 6
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, updateOptions);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="block space" id="map"></div>
<button class="btn preview">Preview</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
function init() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.697299 , -73.809815),
    };
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the HTML as well. This part seems right.

Comment: @Regu this has been updated

Comment: Did you got any error in your browser console?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi it works if i declare the map again. but Regu method says it is not a function

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably because you are trying to re-load the map instead of repositioning and zooming the current one. 
Try like this and let me know:

```
$('.preview').click(function(){
    var width = $('#width').val();
    var height = $('#height').val();
    $('#map').css({
        'width':width,
        'height':height
    });
    map.setZoom(6);
    //map.setCenter() change this is your logic needs it.
});
```

Comment: I get `map.setZoom is not a function` in the console.log im afraid

Comment: Try putting the map as global. It is a function https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

Comment: @regy When I put `var map;` at the start i still get the same error